# Compare two meta key values with between value - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

##### Records in CPT are as follow

| Name | Size From | Size To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Demo 1 | 900 | 6000 |
| Demo 2 | 5000 | 6000 |
| Demo 3 | 7500 | 12000 |
| Demo 4 | 2500 | 7500 |
| Demo 5 | 9000 | 12000 |

```php
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        array(
            'key' => '_size',
            'value'    =>  array(1000, 5000),
            'type'     => 'decimal(10, 2)',
            'compare'  => 'between'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_size_to',
            'value'    =>  array(1000, 5000),
            'type'     => 'decimal(10, 2)',
            'compare'  => 'between'
        ),
    ),
);
```

After applying above `meta_query` not able to get actual output

##### Expected Output

| Name | Size From | Size To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Demo 1 | 900 | 6000 |
| Demo 2 | 5000 | 6000 |
| Demo 4 | 2500 | 7500 |

Actually it's working like below SQL's. Please review once and let me know best fit for this situation.

**Right Now**

```sql
SELECT * FROM test WEHRE _size BETWEEN (1000 AND 5000) OR _size_to BETWEEN (1000 AND 5000)
```

**Trying to do like below**

```sql
SELECT * FROM test WEHRE 1000 BETWEEN (_size AND _size_to) OR 5000 BETWEEN (_size AND _size_to)
```

Comment: I don't see how this would currently behave like those two conditions where joined by an OR - the default value for `relation` is `AND`. And actually specifying `OR` should already solve your problem, I think.

Comment: You need 'relation' => 'AND' to join both in meta_query

Comment: I have added `'relation' => 'OR',` also updated in Question still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many possible ways tried below logic, and it's worked perfectly.

```php
$_max_size = 12000;
$filter_size_rang_min_val = 1000;
$filter_size_rang_max_val = 5000;

if ($_max_size == $filter_size_rang_max_val) {
    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_size',
            'value' => $filter_size_rang_min_val,
            'type'     => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_size_to',
            'value' => $_max_size,
            'type'     => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
    );
} else {
    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_size',
            'value'    =>  $filter_size_rang_max_val,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_size_to',
            'value'    =>  $filter_size_rang_min_val,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'  => '>='
        ),
    );
}
```

Here I compared two conditions,

##### When I filter like Min[1000] & Max[12000]

```
_size >= 1000
_size_to >= 12000
```

##### When I filter like Min[1000] & Max[5000]

```
_size <= 5000
_size_to >= 1000
```